# C++ Null Test After Dereference

Tags: c++

I have the below c++ code

```
   *dtcStatus = DataDTC[idxDTC].status;
    if (dtcStatus != NULL) {
        return E_OK;
    } else {
        ALOGE("Dem_GetStatusOfDTC return NULL");
        return E_NOT_OK;
    }
```

My static analysis tool is reporting warning for the above code  Null Test After Dereference

Comment: This is not jeopardy, please tell us what question you have ;)
But the tool is definitely correct.

Comment: Please give us a [mre].  We need to know what `DataDTC[idxDTC].status` and `dtcStatus` is.

Comment: my static code reading tool tells me that this is a bunch of undeclared variables, though the Null test after dereference I can see too. What is your question?

Comment: The null test after dereference comes from the pointer check against null (dtcStatus != NULL).Any way to over come that

Comment: perhaps check for null before you dereference

Comment: The analysis tool is telling you exactly what the issue is. You are dereferencing `dtcStatus` and assigning it a value. Only after you do this, do you check for `NULL`. If `dtcStatus` is `NULL`, then dereferencing it would be UB (and likely crash).

Answer (score 4):

> My static analysis tool is reporting warning for the above code Null Test After Dereference

This is where you indirect (dereference) through the pointer:

> ```
> *dtcStatus = DataDTC[idxDTC].status;
> ```

This is where you test for null:

> ```
> if (dtcStatus != NULL) {
> ```

If look closely, you'll notice that the indirection is before the check. If the program would enter the else branch, then it must have indirected through a null pointer and thus the behaviour of the program is undefined. This is why the tool informs you of this bug.

> Any way to over come that

You can over come "testing for null after dereference" by not doing that. In other words, by testing for null **before** the indirection. Simply swap those two lines.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
*dtcStatus = DataDTC[idxDTC].status;
```

is dereferencing `dtcStatus` (via the `*` operator). You are only allowed to do that when you are absolutely certain that `dtcStatus` is a valid pointer, ie points to some instance, ie is not `NULL`.

Now the static analyzer tries to tell you that either

- you are absolutely certain that the pointer is valid. In that case you do not have to check whether it is `NULL` on the next line. Or...
- you are not certain. In this case you should check for `NULL` **before** you dereference the pointer.

Comment: yes , i have removed the null check after de reference and the tool is no more showing the warnings.But is there a chance that the pointer can be null after dereference?

Comment: @dev Yes, if it  was null before the dereference. You have to make sure it is valid, before dereferencing it (either by an explicit check for null or in a different way)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is actually telling you what's wrong

> Null Test After Dereference

Means you are trying to test a variable with NULL after dereferencing it.

You should rather not dereference your variable for the NULL check:

```
if (DataDTC[idxDTC].status != NULL) {}
```

Or if you want still want to use your variable you could test `&dtcStatus`.

Comment: the offending line is `*dtcStatus = DataDTC[idxDTC].status`, ie `dtcStatus` is a pointer, but `DataDTC[idxDTC].status` is probably not a pointer

Answer (score -2):

Remove the star at the beginning here:

```
*dtcStatus = DataDTC[idxDTC].status;
```